# Node js : HTTP POST : Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post

I am making an GCM app, so when I need a server to match a fair.

There is a code made by Node js.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        key1: '안녕하세요.',
        key2: 'saltfactory push demo'
        }
    });

var server_access_key = '~';
var sender = new gcm.Sender(server_access_key);
var registrationIds = [];

var registration_id = '~-~-~-~-~~~-~';
// At least one required
registrationIds.push(registration_id);

app.post('/enroll',function(request,response){
var my_number = Number(request.param('myphonenumber'));
var another_number = Number(request.param('anotherphonenumber'));

console.log(my_number);
console.log(another_number);

response.send(my_number);
response.send(another_number);
response.json({success:1});
response.json({success:"my_number"});
response.json({success:"another_number"});

});

http.createServer(app).listen(52273,function(){
    console.log('Server Running');
});
```

And when I execute POST at POST-MAN , I get nothing in browser and
my terminal shows this error code :

```
   NaN
   NaN
   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/~)
at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/Users/~)
at ServerResponse.res.send (/Users/~)
at ServerResponse.res.json (/Users/~)
at /Users/~
at callbacks (/Users/~)
at param (/Users/~)
at pass (/Users/~)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/~)
```

NaN is caused by

```
console.log(my_number);
console.log(another_number);
```

I don't know why NaN is printed. I obviously insert Key : myphonenumber, anotherphonenumber & value : 12345678, 98765432.

Comment: try sending `response` only once, you can create a plain object and store all the data in that. So don't use `.send` or `.json` multiple times in a call. And about `NaN`, i think you're not getting the response, try `console.log` on `request` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use response.json or response.send method more than one time

```
 app.post('/enroll/:myphonenumber/:anotherphonenumber',function(request,response){
   var my_number = Number(request.params.myphonenumber);
   var another_number = Number(request.params.anotherphonenumber);
   console.log(my_number);
   console.log(another_number);
   response.json({'my_number':my_number,'another_number':another_number,success:1});
 });
```